# How to get Excel to accept tab and cr from barcode scanner?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-excel-2013, barcode-scanner

I'm collecting some data in Excel via Code128 barcodes using a Motorola DS6878 scanner.

The first data is a product number and the second is a color. The spreadsheet is set up with those two columns in that order.

I also have Code128 barcodes for the Tab character and the CR character.

So I want to:

1. Scan the product number
2. Scan Tab
3. Scan the color
4. Scan CR

and repeat that until done.

This all works fine in Notepad.

In Excel, it's not accepting the Tab or the CR.

Is there a configuration option I can set in Excel to make it recognize the Tab and CR characters from the barcode scanner as if they had come from the keyboard?

Comment: You mean you want to do something like **text to columns** defining print character as the delimiter?

Comment: As weird as it sounds... you could set up Code128 to send 'Alt+Z', for example, and have AutoHotKey respond to Alt+Z with sending Tab. Same can be done for CR.

Comment: @Raystafarian, I just want Excel to behave as if the input came from the keyboard. It does accept alpha-numerics and other keyboard symbols from the scanner as if they came from the keyboard, but it does not accept the Tab or CR character from the scanner.

Comment: @Wutnaut, that's an interesting idea. Have you done that before?

Comment: @JonathanM No, just an idea. I do like working with AHK and I'd be happy to help you with the scripting if it's an issue for you.